# jenkins pipeline groovy.sql.Sql NotSerializableException

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

there is a problem with the class groovy.sql.Sql inside jenkinsfile.
We are using `groovy.sql.Sql` to call DB.
Try with simple import groovy.sql.Sql we are take error:
    java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.sql.Sql

Then, try to hide this class inside shell class in jenkins file, like this:

```
class Shell{
   private groovy.sql.Sql sql
   Shell(){
      sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@$TNS", login, password, driver)
   }

   String callSql(String stmnt){
      return sql.firstRow(stmnt).Variablename
   }
}
```

But get another error "MissingPropertyException: No such property: Sql for class".
Can u help to fix this problem?

Comment: Could you also show the code of the original error (java.io.NotSerializableException)?

Comment: import groovy.sql.Sql      
    import java.sql.Driver      


      Sql sql
      String userId      
            pipeline {            
          agent any      
    stages {      

        stage("1") {
            steps {
                script {
                    initializeClassPath()
                }
                script {
                    sql = initializeSql()
                }
                script {
                    userId = initializeUser(sql)
                }
            }
        }
Where methods is @NonCPS methods below pipeline